# RavenDB - retrieving part of document

Tags: ravendb

I am playing with Raven DB for few days and I would like to use it as a storage for my Web chat application. I have document which contains some user data and chat history - which is big collection chat messages.

Each time I load user document chat history is also loaded, even if I need only few fields like: user name, password and email.

My question is: how to load only part of document from database ?

Comment: Your question was answered correctly by Ayende. Mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Tomek,

You can't load a partial document, but you *can* load a projection.

```
session.Query<User>()
   .Where(x=>x.Name == name)
   .Select( x=> new { x.Name, x.Email });
```

That will load only the appropriate fields

Comment: This will return a dynamic type. How can I make it return a strong typed object instead? e.g. a 'UserInfo' object?

Comment: It will return an anonymous object, not a dynamic type. You can also just do new MyObject { Name = x.Name, Email = x.Email }

Comment: `var results = Session.Query<Student>().Select(s => { return new ReferencedStudent { Id = s.Id, Name = s.Name }; });` gives me the error _A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree_.  Seems like the compiler picks the wrong overload. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok. I got it. Loosing the curly braces did the trick: `var results = Session.Query<Student>().Select(s => new ReferencedStudent { Id = s.Id, Name = s.Name });`

Answer (score 5):

From what I've seen you can do this (based on the original "User" scenario above):

```
public class UserSummary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
documentSession.Query<User>().AsProjection<UserSummary>();
```

Looking at the Raven server it spits this out as part of the query:

```
?query=&pageSize=128&fetch=Name&fetch=Email&fetch=Id
```

So it looks like it is querying and returning only a subset of the original object, which is good.

This also works:

```
documentSession.Query<User>().Select( x=> new User { Name = x.Name, Email= x.Email })
```

But I don't think that is as clean as returning a UserSummary object.

**Some follow up questions to those who have posted responses:**

The link to RaccoonBlog has this example:

https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/RaccoonBlog.Web/Infrastructure/Indexes/PostComments_CreationDate.cs

Would that method be preferred over the .AsProjection()? What is the difference between the two approaches?

Comment: It seems, that `AsProjection<>()` doesn't exist in RavenDB v3.5 anymore, as I can't find it in the [source code](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb).

Answer (score 2):

Tomek, you cannot load only a part of the document.

However, I understand the problem in your case. I recommend to use two seperate documents for each user: One that actually contains the users data (name, passwordhash, email, etc.) and one that contains *all* the users messages. That way, it is still very cheap to load all the messages of a user and also to load a list of user for general purposes.

This is actually quite similar to how one would model a blog-domain, where you have a post and the posts comments. Take a look at [RaccoonBlog](https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog) to see how this works.